# Apply Same where clause to both sides of outer join with the same table structure

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

I am performing an `outer join` on two tables with the exact same structure. My tables are `year1` and `year2`.

In the example below, both tables have the field `fieldA`

I started with a **nested select** to avoid the problem with `Ambiguous column name 'fieldA'`

#### option 1: too slow

```
  select * from (
     select * from year1 
     outer join year2
     on year1.fieldB= year2.fieldB) fullQuery
     where fieldA <> 'foo'
```

However this ended up being too slow, so I need to 'copy' the where clause for each table

#### option 2: Fast, but our application does not provide table prefixes in where clause

```
  select * from year1 
     outer join year2
     on year1.fieldB= year2.fieldB 
     where year1.fieldA <> 'foo' and year2.fieldA <> 'foo' 
      --where clause duplicated for the tables
```

Unfortunately, our application generates a long where clause without the table prefixes, and it would be messy to try to do string manipulation within the application to insert them

### Question:

How can I avoid the `ambiguous column name` without appending the table name to each condition of the where clause?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot avoid the error in TSQL without the table name.  You could make a view for each year and prefix the columns in the view (ID in the year 1 view would by year1_id) and then join the views.  Another option, depending on what your application is doing and how much control you have with it, is creating a dynamic query but there are risks if you do not have control over the application inputs.

Comment: Create a VIEW as required, and reference it from the application.

Comment: You could look into synonyms (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187552.aspx).  Although I think the VIEW suggestion above is a better way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors at *OUTER JOIN* in your sql, you can't select rows with more than 1 column with same name in a subselect, I corrected this. 
Had to use a strange workaround to prevent using prefix in the WHERE clause. Here is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  year1
JOIN
  (SELECT 1 x) x -- this way rows where fieldA='foo' is eliminated
ON               -- without using the WHERE clause
  year1.fieldA <> 'foo'
LEFT JOIN -- outer join is incorrect syntax
  year2 
ON
  year1.fieldB= year2.fieldB
  and year2.fieldA <> 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try named sub query to achieve the result.

```
 SELECT * FROM (
        ( SELECT * FROM year1 where  fieldA <> 'foo' ) year1
        FULL OUTER JOIN 
        ( SELECT * FROM year2 where  fieldA <> 'foo' ) year2
        ON year1.fieldB= year2.fieldB
     )
```

You can use views instead of named sub query.

> Please note that this is not the best solution, but considering your
>   situation it should be a viable workaround.

Comment: Your answer has inherited the same syntax errors as the original question, you also introduced a new error by not naming the subselect

Comment: @t-clausen.dk , Try using the query now. The correct syntax is using `FULL OUTER JOIN`